# Android Maps API key is correct, yet map not displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

#### TL;DR

We need to move

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

under

```
</application>
```

### Original question

Hi,
I am a newbie in android development.
I tried the "Hello Google Maps" tutorial and I am not able to view the map.
I signed up for API key.
I am using Eclipe which is installed in on the "D" drive. Used following command to obtain MD5 fingerprint from the bin folder of my jdk installation:

`c:\program files\java\jdk 1.6\bin> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android`

I got this fingerprint

`21:17:B1:D8:01:BD:F2:5A:9F:C9:A3:01:96:FA:9A:5B`

Used this to find the API key and got this

`"0Gm7C3R3R2K1pmQGuGkS0rx582TWJEBdJwryFrA"`

Used the following code in layout

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="0Gm7C3R3R2K1pmQGuGkS0rx582TWJEBdJwryFrA"
             />
```

Still map is not displayed.
Please enlighten me on this.
Thanks in advance

#### LogCat Error log

```
11-25 03:14:38.432: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10857): ERROR: thread attach failed
11-25 03:14:42.162: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10866): ERROR: thread attach failed
11-25 03:14:45.562: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10877): ERROR: thread attach failed
11-25 03:14:47.402: ERROR/MapActivity(10885): Couldn't get connection factory client
11-25 03:14:50.652: ERROR/PackageInstallationReceiver(6465): Remove /data/local/tmp/com.testGoogleMap.apk Fail!
11-25 03:14:58.952: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(1683): wpa_supplicant_ctrl_iface_ap_scan: 2
11-25 03:14:58.952: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(1683): Scan request
11-25 03:14:59.802: ERROR/wpa_supplicant(1683): wpa_supplicant_ctrl_iface_ap_scan: 1
```

#### My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.helloGoogleMaps"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_INTERNET"/>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />


</manifest>
```

#### Modified manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:debuggable="true">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Comment: Can you also look into LogCat and see what error messages (if any) are being displayed there ? In Eclipse, Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat

Comment: The version you are installing on the phone is actually signed with the debug key right? Also is there any special reason you have the `uses-library` description in there twice?

Comment: @Ankit Sachan: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Octavian: I tried that initially but no success

Comment: @Ankit Sachan: You should still use the correct one tho. Does your device have a strong signal or is it connected to a WiFi network?

Comment: @Octavian: its connected to WiFi

Comment: ok got the answer we need to move <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> after </applications> tag

Comment: @Ankit Sachan: Only the `uses-library` part has to be inside the `application` tags other than that it doesn't matter where the `uses-permission` part is as long as it is inside the `manifest`.

Comment: @Ankit Sachan: I'm almost 100% certain that the problem was due to having the `uses-library` part outside of the `application` tag and that you've tired to set `ACCESS_INTERNET` as a permission.

Comment: @Ankit Sachan When you reach an answer (and it's your own) then post it as an additional answer, otherwise you'll pollute the original question.

Comment: @gary: I'll do that gary

Comment: Hi all I also have the same problem. I have made the corrections as told in this post, I am still getting the following error- Package " " requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; ignoring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of some permissions in your manifest, here is a working example of an AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest package="<your package>"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> 

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:debuggable="true">   

      <activity android:name="<package>.Activity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" ></uses-library>

    </application>

  </manifest>
```

Look into your manifest and check if :

- the `INTERNET` permission is there
- the `uses-library` is there

Comment: Thanks. After looking at this, I noticed that the <uses-permissions> tags must be outside the <application> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you run it on an emulator with a Google API image otherwise you are not going to have Google Maps installed on the emulator.

**Update:** Just spotted the mistake. It is not `ACCESS_INTERNET` but only `INTERNET` for the permission. So `android.permission.INTERNET`.